# Can't use Cursor with get_users_tweets in Tweepy v2 API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent 3200 tweets from a user with the Tweepy v2 API.  I authenticate fine and find the user with:

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token,....
user = client.get_user(username=screen_name)
```

I can't seem to use a Cursor to get the tweets like this:

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(client.get_users_tweets,
                       id=user.data.id,
                       count=200).items(3200)
```

The error is "tweepy.errors.TweepyException: This method does not perform pagination". The Tweepy docs say that get_users_tweets does support pagination, though.

**ETA traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sean/projects/misc/./tweet-dump.py", line 71, in <module>
    get_all_tweets("Daily_Epsilon")
  File "/Users/sean/projects/misc/./tweet-dump.py", line 23, in get_all_tweets
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(client.get_users_tweets,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 40, in __init__
    raise TweepyException('This method does not perform pagination')
tweepy.errors.TweepyException: This method does not perform pagination
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tweepy.Cursor` handles pagination for the Twitter API V1.1.

Since you are using Twitter API V2, you have to use a `tweepy.Paginator` (see [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/v2_pagination.html)).

So your code should be something like that:

```py
# Please note that the count argument is called max_results in this method
paginator = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, id=user.data.id, max_results=200)

for tweet in paginator.flatten(limit=3200):
    print(tweet)
```